# RegEx that must have at least 3 alpha characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a expression to check that a response has at least three letters.  Numbers, spaces and all other characters are valid. What I have below only works if a special character doesn't come first.

```
(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){3,})^[a-zA-Z0-9].+$
```

Comment: That's because ^ means 'begins with'. Do you have an example you are testing against?

Comment: This would be a valid response. "* 3 of us."

Answer (score 8):

You can use a much simpler regex: `([a-zA-Z].*?){3}`

This matches a letter, optionally followed by other characters, repeated three times.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*){3}
```

Matches (a letter, followed by any non-letters) 3 times.  The `(?:)` makes it a little more efficient because the regex engine does not have to capture.

Of course it might be easier to read and understand without the regex.  Here's C#/linq example.

```
if (s.Count(char.IsLetter) >= 3)
{
   // is valid.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution: `(.*[a-zA-Z].*){3}`

It is pretty similar to @SLaks'; the difference is that my code works if you have alpha characters enclosed in special characters like `<script>`.

@ridgerunner has a neat solution, but if the end of the string is an special character it won't match. You can see the example in this image:

[image: @ridgerunner Regex tested]

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers use the correct definition of a letter.

A letter is not `[a-zA-Z]`. Here's the Unicode category of lowercase letters: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Ll

It includes 2,155 entries, because latin is not the only alphabet in the world. For example, the Ukrainian phrase "Слава Україні!" doesn't pass the `[a-zA-Z]+` regex. (https://regex101.com/r/n7PINx/1)

To correctly classify letters, use the unicode letter category with the `\p{L}` element: `\p{L}{3}` matches at least three letters, therefore the regex `(\p{L}.*?){3}` will match any string that has at least three letters. Additionally, you might want to anchor the regex to make sure it's the whole string that gets matched: `^(.*?\p{L}.*?){3}$` (https://regex101.com/r/sQQXtR/1).

Saying `\p{L}` is much more robust than `[a-zA-Z]`, and also more self-explanatory – it's the letter group, not "these particular range of ASCII".